# Perform a groupby and aggregation in Python Pandas

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, group-by, pandasql

I have a dataframe that looks like

```
user    time15min             name                  is_purchase
A       2015-08-18 16:45:00   Words With Friends    0
A       2015-08-18 16:45:00   Clash of Clans        0
A       2015-08-18 16:45:00   Words With Friends    0
A       2015-08-18 16:45:00   Clash of Clans        1
A       2015-08-18 17:00:00   Sudoku                0
B       2015-08-18 17:00:00   Angry Birds           0
B       2015-08-18 17:00:00   Candy Crush           0
B       2015-08-18 17:00:00   Candy Crush           0
....
```

The `time15min` column contains the 15 min bucket that a game was played by a user in the mobile phone.

What I need to do is to create an aggregated dataframe that has for each user and each time15min slot, have a column showing which game was played most and if there was any in-app purchase during that time.

So, the result would be like

```
 user   time15min             name                  purchase_made
  A     2015-08-18 16:45:00   Clash of Clans        1
  A     2015-08-18 17:00:00   Sudoku                0
  B     2015-08-18 17:00:00   Candy Crush           0
```

In case there is a tie as in the first case for A, we can just take the first alphabetical one (Clash of Clans in this case).

Answer (score 3):

You can apply the recipe from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26701849/pandas-groupby-and-finding-maximum-in-groups-returning-value-and-count)

```
import pandas as pd
## read in your data from clipboard and get the columns right
df = pd.read_clipboard(sep='\s{2,}')

df.loc[:,'time15min'] = pd.to_datetime(df['time15min'])

## set the index to time15min, so df2 has a DateTimeIndex
df2 = df.set_index('time15min')

## Use .agg to count the names and total the purchases
df3=df2.groupby(['user',pd.TimeGrouper('15min'),'name']).agg({
                           'name':'count','is_purchase':'sum'})

## Create a mask to find the max for each group
mask = df3.groupby(level=[0,1]).agg('idxmax')
df3_count = df3.loc[mask['name']]

df3_count
```

This gives the following result:

```
                                           name is_purchase
user    time15min           name        
A   2015-08-18 16:45:00     Clash of Clans  2   1
    2015-08-18 17:00:00     Sudoku          1   0
B   2015-08-18 17:00:00     Candy Crush     2   0
```

Comment: How did you create df2 here? I didn't quite get the part where df2 is created from df.

Comment: Sorry there was a typo: it should be `df2 = df.set_index('time15min')`